# How to make a save function for a java based android app?

Tags: java, android, save

I have an app that encrypts inputs and I want to put a save function that will let users access the "notes" at any time. I thought about adding each in output to an ArrayList, but I still don't know how to save it and display it for the user to select. If you need me to clarify anything I'd be happy to. Thanks.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want to know how to make a save feature, so users can save their encrypted inputs.

Comment: So first welcome to StackOverflow.  This site is for asking specific questions related to programming.  It looks like you're looking for instruction or a tutorial, and this might not be the best place to find it.  If you've tried to write your app and are having a problem that you want to ask about, this is that place!

Comment: Thanks, do you know any good sites for tutorials?

Comment: just google is the best site... always google it when you are stuck :)